# Select 5 previous records, middle and 5 next records in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that the title may be not much to say, but I didn't know how to present that.
I want to make a script in php, but i dont know how to make a good query. I want query which work like that: user type name that he want and he gets: 5 records which has price >= than inputed name, inputed record, 5 records which has price <= than inputed name.

Database schema:

```
id - int
name - string
price - int
```

Example data:

```
1 test1 500
2 test2 400
3 test3 333
4 test4 666
5 test5 500
6 test6 111
7 test7 500
8 test8 222
9 test9 777
10 test10 888
11 test11 333
12 test12 444
```

Expected result when we type 'test7':

```
10 test10 888
9 test9 777
4 test4 666
5 test5 500
1 test1 500
7 test7 500 - middle record
12 test12 444
2 test2 400
11 test11 333
3 test3 333
8 test8 222
```

I did something like that, but there are 2 problems:

```
( 
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price` FROM `items` WHERE `price` >= price_select2 AND `name` != input_name ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price` FROM `items` WHERE `name` = 'test7'
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT `id`, `name`, `price` FROM `items` WHERE `price` <= price_select2 AND `name` != input_name ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 5
)
```

1. i dont know how to get name and price from 2 select in 1 and 3 select (maybe variables, but i dont know how to use it properly)
2. first 5 records is in bad order, i want to reverse that.

Comment: in Oracle I would use the analytic functions, but I don't know, if something like this is available in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `union all`:

```
(select i.*
 from items i
 where price <= (select price from items i2 where name = @input_name)
 order by price desc
 limit 6
) union all
(select i.*
 from items i
 where price > (select price from items i2 where name = @input_name)
 order by price asc
 limit 5
)
```

If you want to order these by price, then add `order by price` to the end of the query.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, but this is not work as i want. Your query shows: `middle record, 5 <= descending, 5 >= ascending` instead `5 >= descending, middle record, 5 <= descending`.

Comment: @exexe, you can take Gordon's query, insert it into a temp table, then select from it, ordering by price. That should give you the order you want.

Comment: @SGrimminck, actually i did this and try in phpmyadmin.Check this [image](http://i.imgur.com/HvDw00M.png)

Comment: After adding `order by price` at the end, it worked perfectly. Many thanks!